# After updating from Eclipse 2020-06 to 2020-09, Java support is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-jdt

I was developing in Java on Eclipse for Java Developers 2020-06 on Windows 10 and decided to run updates, which installed Eclipse 2020-09. When Eclipse restarted, I created a new workspace. When I opened `Preferences`, there was no longer a Java section. The only Java search result was in Oomph:

[image: Eclipse preferences]

The Java `New Project` wizard was also gone. (I checked under `Other`.)

The installation details still show Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and Eclipse Java Development Tools:

[image: Installation Details]

How do I reenable Java support?

**Update**

Here is the `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.800.v20200727-1323.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1300.v20200819-0940
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear, I assume you have specified a Java 11 JDK (or newer) in the "-vm" arguments in your "eclipse.ini" file?  2020-09 requires at least Java 11 to run.

I would create a new workspace.

Comment: Adding the lines `-vm` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\javaw.exe` fixed the problem. Thank you so much!